# How did Lister to come exist in the parallel universe?

Tags: red-dwarf

In Season 7, Episode 3 - Ourouboros we find out about Lister's parents.

Let's call the universe we see most often Universe A, and the other universe they encounter in that episode, Universe B:

- Kochanski B ends up stuck in Universe A
- Lister A and Kochanski B have a child
- Lister A goes back in time and places the child under a pool table.
- The child is Lister, forever looping his own time line.

The question is how did Lister B come to exist? Lister B is a hologram by this point anyway.

Is this just a plot hole?

Answer (score 7):

<sub><sup>I shall start by ignoring the fact that the answer is quite clearly "[because it's funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)!"</sup></sub>

Theoretically, the parallel universe that you've dubbed "Universe B" could have been formed *after* Lister was conceived and sent back in time. That would allow **both universes** to have their own Lister and would also account for the very small differences between the two universes.

You may also wish to note that Lister has crossed his own timeline more often than Dr Who doing the conga. This has included travel to other alternate universes, interdimensional travel and time travel using at least five different methods. It's hardly beyond the realms of possibility that any one of these events could have led to a duplicate Lister being unknowingly left behind in an alternate universe.

Comment: +2 for finding a rationale for this. -1 for calling no one a smeghead in the process.

Comment: “Lister has crossed his own timeline more often than Dr Who doing the conga” — is this a line from the show? If not, it should be. You’re hired.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - All my own work.